# Left align in fortran format

Tags: fortran

Is it possible to left align a printed out value in Fortran, instead of the default right alignment ?

For example, I have formatters like this

`"(A3,10A12)"`

and

`"(A1, I12, 9F12.6)"`

I would like the strings and numbers printed with these formatters to be left aligned, instead of right aligned.

Comment: everything is right aligned, I think the answer M. S. B. gave with the writing to string is the only loop-hole out of that.  The idea with right aligning is that when using the same format, periods are aligned.

Answer (score 6):

Isn't right-justified the default?

If you first write a number to a string, you could use the intrinsics adjustL or adjustR to get either adjustment, then output the string.

Comment: Yes, I meant the opposite. Sorry. I could not sleep tonight (I am jet lagged 10 hours)